# Is there a way to generate image stretch distortion using algorithms or specific patterns?

Tags: image, image-processing

[image]How to generate stretched distortion in image like the one in the image?

I tried to check the pixels. They have some linearity, but I wondered if there is some pattern or algorithm to do that. Also i checked ImageMagick available distortions but i did not find anything like this pattern.

Comment: Please show the input image without the distortion.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following in Imagemagick.

Pick two rows at y=140 and 270. Crop them. Append them. Resize to the difference of 130 height. Insert that into the image starting at y=140.  Given that the image width = 400, we have

Input:

[image]

Unix Syntax for Imagemagick 6:

```
convert barn.jpg \
\( -clone 0 -crop "400x1+0+140" +repage \) \
\( -clone 0 -crop "400x1+0+270" +repage \) \
\( -clone 1,2 -append -filter triangle -resize 400x131! \) \
-delete 1,2 \
-geometry +0+140 -compose over -composite \
barn_interp.png
```

Result:

[image]